# moduli of the conjugates of a cyclotomic integer

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I saw a theorem on the modulus of a cyclotomic integer:

[Theorem] If every conjugate $\alpha '$of a cyclotomic integer $\alpha$ satisfies $|\alpha '|<\sqrt{2}$, then $\alpha$ is $0$ or a root of unity.

It can be shown by a simple expansion argument. In particular:

[Corollary] If every conjugate $\alpha '$of a cyclotomic integer $\alpha$ satisfies $|\alpha '|<1$, then $\alpha=0.$

Can I generalize it? i.e., is there a theorem of the following type?

[Conjecture for $n$, $k$] There are a positive integer $n$ and a positive real number $k<1$ such that if the rate $r$ of conjugates $\alpha '$ of a cyclotomic integer $\alpha\in\mathcal{O}_m$ with $|\alpha '|<1$ satisfies $r \ge k,$ then $\alpha=0$, where $\mathcal{O}_m$ is the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\xi_m)$ with $m\ge n$.

The case of [Corollary] is that $n=1=k$. Otherwise, can we always find  good counterexamples? That is,

[Conjecture'] There is a sequence of cyclotomic integers $\{\alpha_m\}_{m\ge 1},\alpha_m\in\mathcal{O}_m$ such that all conjugates $\alpha'_m$ of $\alpha_m$ satisfy $|\alpha'_m|<1$ except one and only one conjugate $\alpha''_m$ with $|\alpha''_m|\ge 1.$

Is either [Conj.](for some $n$, $k$) or [Conj.'] true? What can we say about the ring of algebraic integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second conjecture is true, as long as $m \neq 3, 4, 6$. In particular, there is always a [Pisot number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number) in the maximal totally real subfield of $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_m)$. (This actually holds for any totally real field, though this stronger fact is not necessary here.) You may also be interested in [Mahler measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahler_measure) and [Lehmer's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer%27s_conjecture).

In general, you can't have such a number that generates $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_m)$ as any complex number shares an absolute value with its complex conjugate.

I'm not sure what you are asking about when you ask what can be said about the ring of integers, as the ring of integers of $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_m)$ is always $\mathbf{Z}[\zeta_m]$.